# How to Clip Rasters in Parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, raster, pool, arcpy

I'm working through a multiprocessing example ([An introduction to parallel programming](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html)). I modified the Pool Class example to meet my specific needs--to clip a bunch of rasters with a study area polygon in parallel. On the plus side, the script finishes and prints "Processing Complete.". On the negative side, there is no output generated. I suspect that I have some procedural error in the `pool.apply_async' function. Why is this script producing no results?

```
import arcpy, os
import multiprocessing as mp

arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\temp\inws'
outws_utm11 = r'F:\temp\outws'
clipper_utm11 = r'F:\temp\some_polygon.shp'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

def clip_raster(clipper, outws, raster):
        arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", os.path.join(outws, raster), clipper, nodata_value = 0, clipping_geometry = "ClippingGeometry")

[pool.apply_async(clip_raster, args=(clipper_utm11,outws_utm11, ras)) for ras in rasters]

print "Processing complete."
```

Answer (score 2):

The `apply_async` function kicks off your function in a worker process, but *does not block* until the function completes. You're letting the main process complete and exit instead of waiting for the workers to finish. This causes them to be killed, which is likely hapenning before they can create your output.

Since you're just applying the same function to all of your items in the `rasters` list, you should consider using [pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) instead. It will accept both a function name and an iterable object as its arguments, and call the function on each of the items in the list. All of these function calls will occur in a worker process in the pool. One caveat of the `pool.map` function though, is that the function object you pass it must only accept one argument: the item from the list. I see your `clip_rasters` function uses a couple of other arguments, so in my example below, I'm using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a new version of `clip_raster` that *always* includes the first two arguments. This new function that has `clipper_utm11` and `outws_utm11` bound to it can now be used with `pool.map`.

```
import arcpy, os
import functools
import multiprocessing as mp

arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\temp\inws'
outws_utm11 = r'F:\temp\outws'
clipper_utm11 = r'F:\temp\some_polygon.shp'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

def clip_raster(clipper, outws, raster):
        arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", os.path.join(outws, raster), clipper, nodata_value = 0, clipping_geometry = "ClippingGeometry")

bound_clip_raster = functools.partial(clip_raster, clipper_utm11, outws_utm11)
results = pool.map(bound_clip_raster, rasters)

print "Processing complete."
```

This code will call the `bound_clip_raster` function once for each of the items in your `rasters` list, including `clipper_utm11` and `outws_utm11`. All of the results will be available in a list called `results`, and the call to `pool.map` is blocking, so the main process will wait until all the workers are done before it exits.

If, for some strange reason, you're intent on using [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async), then you'll need to add some code to the end of your script to use the [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object's associated methods to block the main process until they can complete, such as `wait()`, or poll for completion in a loop by calling `ready()`. But you should really use `pool.map` for this use case. This is what it's made for.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. This makes sense, although it appears that code throttles up the CPUs to ~35% and just hangs there. No output is generated. I wonder if it could be due to an undefined `raster` variable in the `clip_raster()` function? I'm not sure how the code passes items from the `rasters` list to the function in parallel?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `clip_raster` function actually works correctly on just one item without using any multiprocessing first? If you've already done that, try wrapping the entire body of the function in a try/except block that catches all exceptions and writes a traceback to a file. If a file is created, then you know your functions are throwing exceptions and the traceback in the file should point you to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered a question that may be useful to you too. Take a look here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831763/arcpy-multiprocessing-error-could-not-save-raster-dataset/54318532#54318532)

There are a few good practices, like to put everything inside a function like you did, but also a must have is to put a `main()` function and block it by the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another thing is this one function to call the pool.apply_assync that I've inserted in your code.

Also have made a few modifications so you can try, I've tested and it works for me:

```
import arcpy, os
from multiprocessing import Pool

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Gis\lab_geo\2236622'
outws_utm11 = r'C:\Gis\lab_geo\2236622\outs'
clipper_utm11 = r'C:\Gis\arcpy_teste\teste.shp'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

def clipRaster(clipper, outws, raster):
     arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", os.path.join(outws, raster), clipper, 0, "ClippingGeometry")

def clipRasterMulti(processList):
    pool = Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=10)
    jobs= {}
    for item in processList:
        jobs[item[0]] = pool.apply_async(clipRaster, [x for x in item])
    for item,result in jobs.items():
        try:
            result = result.get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def main():
    processList = [(clipper_utm11,outws_utm11, ras) for ras in rasters]
    clipRasterMulti(processList)
    print "Processing complete."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```